# Añadir nueva option en un select desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy haciendo unos ejercicios con Javascript, ya que estoy aprendiendo, concretamente con temas de formularios, manejo de cookies, etc. El caso, que en un formulario, debo añadir un campo de selección múltiples desde javascript. Para ello, crée un input con un onclick llamando a la función.

El id del select es "aficiones", el del input es "inputAficiones" y la función "añadirAficion()".

Ésta es la función que hice.

```
function añadirAficion(){
    var aficiones = document.getElementById("aficiones");
    var aficionNueva = document.getElementById("nuevaAficion");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = aficionNueva;
    aficiones.add(option);
```

y el html:

```
<label for="aficiones">
        <span>Aficiones: </span>
        <select name="aficiones" id="aficiones" multiple>
          <option value="programar">Programar</option>
          <option value="leer">Leer</option>
          <option value="cantar">Cantar</option>
          <option value="bailar">Bailar</option>
         </select>           
      </label>

<label for="nuevaAficion">Nueva Afición: </label> 
        <input type="text" class="nuevaAficion" id="inputAficion" name="nuevaAficion">
        <button onclick="añadirAficion()">Añadir Afición</button>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o que estoy pasando por alto?

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar estas tratando de llamar a la clase de inputAficiones lo cual se hace con un `document.getElementsByClassName("tu_clase");`, pero puedes usar el id que le colocaste, claro haciendo el llamado a su value, ahora en la parte de `option.text` mandarías `inputAficion`, con eso quedaría.

```js
function añadirAficion(){
    var aficiones = document.getElementById("aficiones");
    var inputAficion = document.getElementById("inputAficion").value;
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = inputAficion;
    aficiones.add(option);
    }
```

```html
<label for="nuevaAficion">Nueva Afición: </label> 
        <input type="text" class="nuevaAficion" id="inputAficion" name="nuevaAficion">
        <button onclick="añadirAficion()">Añadir Afición</button>

<label for="aficiones">
        <span>Aficiones: </span>
        <select name="aficiones" id="aficiones" multiple>
          <option value="programar">Programar</option>
          <option value="leer">Leer</option>
          <option value="cantar">Cantar</option>
          <option value="bailar">Bailar</option>
         </select>           
      </label>
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias Felipe!